# Can a Monk with the Unhindering Shield feat use Heavy Shields effectively?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monk, shield

I had an idea to play a monk who uses a shield in his fighting.  After a little searching, I came across the [Unhindering Shield](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/shield-mastery-feats/unhindering-shield-shield-mastery/) feat.

The feat lists a benefit which is specific to bucklers.

> **Benefit(s):** You still gain a buckler’s bonus to AC even if you use your shield hand for some other purpose. When you wield a buckler, your shield hand is considered free for the purposes of casting spells, wielding weapons, and using any other abilities that require you to have a free hand or interact with your shield, such as the swashbuckler’s precise strike deed or the Weapon Finesse feat.

It then goes on to specify a special benefit without explicitly mentioning bucklers.

> **Special:** A monk with this feat is not considered to be using a shield for the purposes of his AC bonus, fast movement, or flurry of blows.

Does this mean that the 2 sections can be read separately and while the first section only applies to bucklers the second section can apply to any shield w.r.t. monks?  Or does the 1st section's focus on bucklers somehow imply that the 2nd section must also apply only to bucklers?

My GM likes to stay very close to RAW in almost all matters and she allows all Paizo material.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, the fact that the **benefit** section is talking about bucklers has no bearing on the **special** section, since the special section only requires you to *have* the feat, not actually be using it. If it said “While using this feat, a monk [...],” you would have a much harder time making that argument, but it doesn’t say that.

The name and fluff of the feat also reference a “shield,” rather than “buckler” specifically, so there is some reason to think this may even have been intentional.

That said, taking this feat and then *not* using a buckler seems like a poor choice—a heavy shield has only +1 shield bonus more to AC than a buckler, and has several other drawbacks that this shield lacks. Since shield bonuses to AC don’t count towards touch attacks, +1 is *very* close to worthless. Armored AC is (by far) the weakest defense in the game, and after the basics (best armor you can use without losing class features or needing to spend a feat), it’s basically never worth investing in on its own.

Which is another reason to expect it’s fine to allow it to be used with non-bucklers: the feat is quite a lot weaker that way *anyway*. Please don’t fall into that trap though.

Comment: Can you help me understand better why (1) this is a trap and (2) why a monk would have problems with a heavy shield (assuming proficiency) that a buckler wouldn't have?  I'm not looking for an overpowered character, just checking whether I can make such a character viable.

Comment: FWIW, I was toying with the idea of dipping into Warpriest (Bulwark) to lessen the armor check penalty, picking up Shield Focus, etc.

Comment: @NickBrown There are better ways to get +1 to AC than upgrading a bucker to a heavy shield, which don't require you to rely on *poorly worded* feats such as this.

Comment: Why does everyone feel the need to bash armor AC as part of their answers to questions about getting more AC? It may not be as technically strong as bonuses to Saves, Deflection AC, or displacement, but it *is* the easiest to invest in with the highest cap. Others can go up to 5 if you get lucky with treasure rolls while rich, but armor is armor+shield+2 cheap enhancement buffs and *does* significantly reduce the most consistent cause of damage- Full Attack actions. *And* it stacks with other methods of building up your defenses...

Comment: Also, point of fact, DR is the weakest of all defensive measures with only a couple builds getting more than a few and so few things triggering it enough to make a noticeable increase in effective health.

Comment: @Ifusaso When I “bash armored AC,” I am always careful to bash *improving armored AC above the baseline*, that is, beyond armor + shield (if not attacking with a weapon) + basic +1 enhancements on each. It’s a *necklace of natural armor* that I’m really objecting to. Also, I would also bash touch AC, too—far more valuable, but also costlier. A *ring of protection +1* **might** be worth it; higher ones are not. (And yes, I have seen the math.) Likewise the Combat Expertise or Dodge feats, to say nothing of the total defense action, and so on.

Comment: @NickBrown Warpriest is a great class (though I don’t know what you mean by “bulwark,” that doesn’t seem to be a warpriest class feature, blessing, or archetype). It is, in fact, vastly superior to monk in every way—it’s well worth considering just dropping monk entirely (take Improved Unarmed Strike normally if you want). Anyway, the issue with heavy shield here is that you are giving up something valuable (a free hand) for something not valuable (+1 more shield bonus to AC). We can extend that, too: by taking Unhindering Shield, you are giving up something **extremely** valuable (a feat).

Comment: @Ifusaso Normally its only KRyan who bashes it, though I agree with his assessment on that subject. Dodge is probably one of the best options when considering additional AC for a feat, and it is still a bad trade, since that benefit will fade away as you move away from level 1.

Comment: @KRyan [bulwark](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/warpriest/archetypes/paizo-warpriest-archetypes/bulwark-warpriest-archetype/) is an archetype.

Comment: @ShadowKras Huh, wasn’t listed on the table (or, at least, Ctrl+F didn’t find it). Can’t say I think the archetype is a good trade, but nothing about it seems egregiously terrible.

Comment: I shy alway at all archetypes that remove the ability to allow you to add *keen* or *holy* to a weapon on demand. Also, the main class's archetype list is grossly [outdated](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/Archetypes.aspx?Class=Warpriest).

Comment: Yeah Bulwark is one of the ones that is worth it to realize a character concept when you're not worried about needing to optimize your character vs your GM (as opposed to needing to optimize to succeed and archetypes that actively make you *less* viable)

Comment: Btw, I was considering using the shield as a weapon, therefore I would still have a free hand.  I thought it might be fun to have a character whose only weapon was a shield (a la Erik from the D&D animated series or Captain America for the rest of you).

Comment: @NickBrown Ah, well then, that’s a thing then; I thought you were just trying to improve your AC. I had a very fun dual-shield fighter in D&D 3.5e one campaign. If you can port D&D 3.x material, the old 3.0 Improved Shield Bash works *very* nicely with the dungeoncrasher fighter from *Dungeonscape*. Either way, have fun with it.